# Applying a function from a list according to indexing to rows of a matrix in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, data-science

I have a list of functions like so:

```
test_functions = [lambda x: np.sin(x),
                  lambda x: np.sin(x * np.cos(x)),
                  lambda x: np.exp(np.sin(10*x)),
                  lambda x: np.sin(np.exp(np.abs(np.cos(x))))]
```

I also have a matrix `[batch_size, channels, sample_len]` such that each sample represent `x axis` sampling points eg:

```
tensor = [[[0, 2.5, 7]], 
          [[1, 2.5, 3]]]
```

so `batch_size = 2`, `channels = 1` and `sample_len = 3`. where the sample itself means i want to know a functions value at `x=0, x=2.5 and x=7` (for the first example).

I generated a random matrix of ints (`shape=(batch_size, channels)`)such that the entries are the function to be used by index.

for example if the matrix is:
`functions_to_be_used = [[0], [2]]`

Then i want to achieve some sort of indexing that will yeild:

```
result = [[[np.sin(0),            np.sin(2.5),            np.sin(7)]],
           [np.exp(np.sin(10*1)), np.exp(np.sin(10*2.5)), np.exp(np.sin(10*3))]]]
```

Something along the lines (that do not work):

```
result = functions[functions_to_be_used](tensor[:, :, :])
```

I want to refrain from using a for loop for performance sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop over the rows but you can avoid the loop over the columns.  For example:

```
result = [[test_functions[functions_to_be_used[0][0]](tensor[0][0])],
          [test_functions[functions_to_be_used[0][1]](tensor[0][1])]]
```

You should always learn to walk before you run, so ignoring the degenerate outermost dimension, we could do this:

```
result = [[test_functions[functions_to_be_used[0][ii]](tensor[0][ii])] for ii in range(2)]
```

Or:

```
result = []
for funcidx, data in zip(functions_to_be_used[0], tensor[0]):
    result.append([test_functions[funcidx](data)])
```

Extending the dimensions is left as an exercise.  The point is that you pass an entire array (row) to the test_function instead of one scalar value at a time.

If the performance of this is not adequate, I suggest you use Numba which can probably speed it up quite a bit more by compiling the loop code.